# Backbone and Handlebars Render Issue after adding item to collection

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm new to backbone and handlebars.js.  I'm trying to programmatically add a new Item to a collection, and I'd like backbone to render the collection using Render.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
    }
});

var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item
});

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('BODY'), // el attaches to existing element
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here

        this.collection = new List();
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var template = Handlebars.compile($('#screenshot_template').html());
        $(this.el).html(template({
            row: this.collection
        }));
        return this;
    }

});

var listView = new ListView();
window.screenshots = listView;
window.screenshots.collection.add({
    myurl: 'http://placehold.it/350x150'
});
```

My handlebars template looks like:

```
<script id="screenshot_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each row}}
    <div><img src="{{this.myurl}}"></div>
    {{/each }}
</script>
```

Comment: You probably want to say `row: this.collection.toJSON()`, trying to `{{#each}}` over a collection object won't make you very happy.

Comment: @muistooshort THANK YOU.   There are 3 hours I won't get back.

Comment: But three hours you won't have to spend again so it balances out :)

Comment: `<img src='{{this.attributes.myurl}}</div>'` will also work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a listener to your view so it knows when the collection is firing the add event - usually done in the initialize function of your view:

```
this.collection.on('add', this.render);
```

Obviously you'll want to add it after you've instantiated your collection.

Comment: Thanks, this solved that problem.  I guess i could just avoid using handlebars collection syntax and then use a view per model like you say.

Comment: You can still use handlebars for rendering the individual model views - that's how I've used it.